Flink GlobalWindow Trigger only process the trigger event
I have datastream keyby by an event property, that is then passed to a globalwindow, trigged when a specific event comes in, the issue is that when the window is trigged to process the events, it only process the trigger event. Here is the code:
public class MyEvent {
    public String key;
    public String value;

    public MyEvent() {
        // Default constructor
    }

    public MyEvent(String key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Key: " + key + ", Value: " + value;
    }
}




public class KeyedGlobalWindowTriggerExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        DataStream<MyEvent> input = env.socketTextStream("localhost", 9091)
                .map(new MapFunction<String, MyEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public MyEvent map(String value) {
                        // Assuming the input stream is in the format "key,value"
                        String[] parts = value.split(",");
                        return new MyEvent(parts[0], parts[1]);
                    }
                });

        // Key By Event Property
        KeyedStream<MyEvent, String> keyedStream = input
                .keyBy(event -> event.key);

        //Create a Custom Trigger
        keyedStream.window(GlobalWindows.create())
                .trigger(new Trigger<MyEvent, GlobalWindow>() {
                    @Override
                    public TriggerResult onElement(MyEvent event, long timestamp, GlobalWindow window, TriggerContext ctx) {
                        if ("eod".equals(event.getKey())) {
                            return TriggerResult.FIRE;
                        }
                        return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public TriggerResult onProcessingTime(long time, GlobalWindow window, TriggerContext ctx) {
                        return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public TriggerResult onEventTime(long time, GlobalWindow window, TriggerContext ctx) {
                        return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void clear(GlobalWindow window, TriggerContext ctx) {
                        // Handle clearing of window state if necessary
                    }
                })
                .process(new MyProcessWindowFunction())
                .print();

        env.execute("Keyed Global Window Trigger Example");
    }
}

public class MyProcessWindowFunction extends ProcessWindowFunction<MyEvent, String, String, GlobalWindow> {
    @Override
    public void process(String key, Context context, Iterable<MyEvent> elements, Collector<String> out) {
        for (MyEvent element : elements) {
            out.collect(element.toString());
        }
    }
}

How to make sure it process all the events in the globalwindow, with a trigger event?
If I send the following events:
test_one, one
event_two, two
event_three, three
event_four, four
eod, eod
The output is only:
Key: eod, Events: [Key: eod, Value:  eod, ]
I was expecting to see all the events that were sent to this window.

read this, the keyBy function split your event to different window, that is why only eod outputted.
modify your code.

remove KeyedStream<MyEvent, String> keyedStream = input.keyBy(event -> event.key);
change keyedStream.window()   to   input.windowAll()
change
public class MyProcessWindowFunction extends ProcessWindowFunction<MyEvent, String, String, GlobalWindow> { @Override public void process(String key, Context context, Iterable<MyEvent> elements, Collector<String> out) { for (MyEvent element : elements) { out.collect(element.toString()); } } } to public static class MyProcessWindowFunction extends ProcessAllWindowFunction<MyEvent, String, GlobalWindow> { @Override public void process(ProcessAllWindowFunction<MyEvent, String, GlobalWindow>.Context context, Iterable<MyEvent> elements, Collector<String> out) throws Exception { for (MyEvent element : elements) { out.collect(element.toString()); } } }


In that case if I use keyBy, it will create another window per different key? And it is not possible to trigger all windows?

yes, it only can trigger current window.
